# Run a .bat script from Oracle

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql

I have a batch script wich, double-clicked,  populates a table with values imported from a .csv.
I want to execute that script with a PL/SQL script..so I did:

```
    BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB( job_name => 'e_job',
        job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe',
        job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
        comments => 'Job to call batch script on Windows',
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        number_of_arguments => 3,
        enabled => FALSE);

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'e_job', argument_position => 1, argument_value => '/q'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'e_job', argument_position => 2, argument_value => '/c'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'e_job', argument_position => 3, argument_value => '"E:\temp\StartLoad.bat"'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE( 'e_job' ); 


   END;

    BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('example_job');
    END;
```

I didn't get any errors, but my table isn't containing any values.
I must say that my script works fine if executed with double click in windows explorer

Comment: Why don't you use an external table instead? Probably much more reliable than a batch file to import a CSV

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS, USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG, and USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS?

Comment: Is your database running on the same machine that the batch file is on?

Comment: yes, it's on the same machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `CREATE_JOB` call you've named the new job 'e_job', but in the `RUN_JOB` call you're running 'example_job'. Change the `RUN_JOB` call to invoke 'e_job'.

I also suggest that in the batch file you do something that clearly indicates that the batch file has run - try adding `echo I ran OK! > c:\e_job.log` at the very start of the batch file. In that way you can determine that the batch file was executed by looking for the log file.

Comment: Firstly I  runned 'e_job' and nothing happend...I modified to 'example_job' just for a test.  I will try adding that echo

Comment: I tried it and  'I ran OK' appeared in e_log.log, but my table isn't populated

Comment: I suspect that some error is occurring during execution of the batch file, perhaps related to permissions. You might try getting rid of the /q and /c arguments to `cmd` so that the window will persist and you can see what errors occur.